# methods to analyze zero-inflated data

Tags: r

```
type    intact  bury
B          0     0
B          0     0
B          0     0 
B          0     0
B          0     0
B          0     0
M        0.375   0
M        0.05    0
M          0     0
M          0     0
M          0    0.025
M      0.033333333  0
M          0    0.025
M          0    0.025
S        0.025   0
S          0     0
S          0    0.011111111
S      0.166666667  0
S          0    0.033333333
S      0.188888889  0.044444444
S          0        0
S          0      0.02
S          0        0
S          0        0
```

My question is that if I want to use type as factor to estimate its effects on variable intact and bury, which methods do I use? In first, I used generalized linear mixed model, but it didn't work well. So how about zero-inflated model? if does, which package do i need? I have no idea about it. Could you help me and give me some suggestions? Very thanks~

Comment: This has come here from SO as presumably too statistical and too little focused on code for them. Now that it's on CV, I think we expect some context on what these variables are and much more detail on (e.g.) which variable is the response (outcome, dependent variable): is it both `bury` and `intact`? What does "didn't work well" mean? Are the numeric variables probabilities or measurements (on what scale?)?  Are these all the data or just a token subset? Small simple datasets often only allow, or more positively often yield to, small simple analyses.

Comment: Adding to what Nick said, is this all of your data?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the pscl package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/pscl.pdf. This includes methods for Hurdle and zero inflated Poisson methods.

Look at examples from UCLA stats: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/zipoisson.htm. for example

Comment: The hurdle and zero-inflation models in `pscl` are for count data. Here, the data appears to be continuous.

Comment: @Achim Agree. And I was not familiar with the AER packag. Thanks

Comment: The `tobit()` function from `AER` is actually just a convenience interface to `survreg()` from the `survival` package. There are various other packages for censored or truncated Gaussian distributions as well. Also, if the answer was helpful, please credit it it.

Comment: @Achim this is not my question... and I don't have enough rep to give you an upvote.

Comment: Apologies! I didn't look carefully enough and thought you were the OP. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Some standard strategies include censored regression models such as the tobit (zero-censored Gaussian) or continuous hurdle models (combining a binary and a zero-truncated model). Especially if the number of non-zeros is not so large then using only the binary model (0 vs. greater) might also be a good first step.

In your case the question is whether your data set is actually larger than the one reported here. If this is the complete data, then there is not much point in analyzing type B because both response variables are only zero and do not vary at all.

```
d <- read.table(textConnection("type    intact  bury
B          0     0
B          0     0
B          0     0 
B          0     0
B          0     0
B          0     0
M        0.375   0
M        0.05    0
M          0     0
M          0     0
M          0    0.025
M      0.033333333  0
M          0    0.025
M          0    0.025
S        0.025   0
S          0     0
S          0    0.011111111
S      0.166666667  0
S          0    0.033333333
S      0.188888889  0.044444444
S          0        0
S          0      0.02
S          0        0
S          0        0"), header = TRUE)
```

As a first step one could look at the proportion of non-zeros and zeros across the three types:

```
plot(factor(intact == 0) ~ type, data = d)
plot(factor(bury == 0) ~ type, data = d)
```

[image: spineplot]

This pretty much sums up the story: B is only zero and for M and S the proportion of non-zeros is about 30-40%. To analyze the difference between M and S, we can restrict the data and use a simple probit model:

```
d2 <- subset(d, type != "B")
d2$type <- factor(d2$type)
m1 <- glm(factor(intact > 0) ~ type, data = d2,
  family = binomial(link = "probit"))
summary(m1)
## Call:
## glm(formula = factor(intact > 0) ~ type, family = binomial(link = "probit"), 
##     data = d2)
## 
## Deviance Residuals: 
##     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
## -0.9695  -0.9383  -0.8446   1.4006   1.5518  
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)  -0.3186     0.4514  -0.706    0.480
## typeS        -0.2058     0.6144  -0.335    0.738
## 
## (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
## 
##     Null deviance: 22.915  on 17  degrees of freedom
## Residual deviance: 22.802  on 16  degrees of freedom
## AIC: 26.802
## 
## Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Using a tobit model (zero-censored Gaussian) instead of the probit model (binary Gaussian) leads essentially to the same non-significant results and almost the same coefficients (modulo scaling):

```
library("AER")
m2 <- tobit(intact ~ type, data = d2)
coef(m1)
## (Intercept)       typeS 
##  -0.3186394  -0.2057611 
coef(m2)/m2$scale
## (Intercept)       typeS 
##  -0.3144522  -0.2342246
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am so sorry that my network was broken that I could not detailed description. My data is proportional data. All of data is here. Type is explanatory variable and Intact & Bury are response variables.  And I want to know the effects of Type on Intact and Bury respectively. According to your description, you meant that the data of Type-B need not contain in the analysis because it had no variance?  If I want to analyze the rate data, could the methods you describe achieve it?

Comment: If this is the complete data, then it does not matter much what you do, I think. The graphics I posted tell pretty much the whole story.